# How to remove escape char from string in bash using sed?

Tags: bash, unix, sed, escaping, character

I need to remove escape character from the string in bash. I get a data structure, which contains url paths with / escaped so I receive the regular link:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

as one with escaped /:

```
http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/ask
```

Now I need to remove \ from the second link. For this purpose I tried using sed

```
 `echo '"'${paths[$index]}'"' | sed "s@\\@@g"`
```

But I get an error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated `s' command
```

If I replace \\ with ie. _ it works like a charm and removes all occurrences of _ in a string. How do I get rid of escape characters in a string using sed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

```
.......|sed 's@\\@@g'
```

or:

```
.......|sed "s@\\\\@@g"
```

**EDIT** add a test output:

```
kent$  echo "http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/ask"|sed "s@\\\\@@g"
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

kent$  echo "http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/ask"|sed 's@\\@@g'  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

Comment: both ways gave me the same error, but following your logic I tried ........|sed 's@\\\\@@g' and it works! I get why I need \\\\. \ in string is seen as \\ by sed, so i need \\\\ in sed query to match \\. Although I don't know why it doesn't work with "".

Comment: @user1581900 interesting, both worked here..:) see edit in answer

Comment: I am using the whole echo pipe and sed in between ` ` inside another echo statement which uses "". Only sed 's@\\\\@@g' works inside this statement but in terminal all approaches work.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't clear about which way round you want so here is both ways:

```
$ sed 's@/@\\/@g' <<< "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/ask

$ sed 's@\\/@/@g' <<< "http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/ask"
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

Comment: he just wants to remove all backslashes.

Comment: @Kent: Presumably not **all**!

Comment: @Kent his `sed` command indicates that yes but he states `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` becomes `http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/ask` so which way round he actually wants it ambiguous.

Comment: @sudo_O ..aha... read the title of this question... i think he is trying to get from `\/` -> `/`

Comment: Yes I want to replace all occurrences of \/ to /

Comment: You want `sed 's@\\/@/@g'` then otherwise **all** backslashes will be removed not just those escaping `/`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `sed`.

```
paths[index]=${paths[index]//\\/}
```

or simply

```
echo ${paths[index]//\\/}
```

to see the result without modifying the value in-place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
sed 's@\\@@g'
```

But the problem is when you encounter a backslash that you actually want in the string, but is escaped. In that case :

```
sed 's/\\\\/\x1/' |sed 's/[\]//g' | sed 's/\x1/\\/g'
```

Replaces the double backslash with with a temp character[SOH], replaces all other backslashes and then restores the backslash that is needed.